# Why doesn't java.util.Optional implement Iterable?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Why doesn't Java 8's `Optional` implement `Iterable`?

I assume it's a deliberate language choice but I'm wondering why. Scala's `Option` and Haskell's `Maybe` implement traversal methods analogous to `Iterable`.  FWIW, Java 9 will implement `Optional.stream()` ([JDK-8050820](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050820)).

Comment: "Why" questions should really be addressed to the developers of the language. There is no way an unaffiliated person, an expert though he or she may be in the use of the language, will be able to answer that.

Comment: I don't know, but why would you want to iterate of 1 var, that is either null or set?

Comment: I'm making a few assumptions here, but maybe OP wants an Optional<List<Object>> and just get the iterator directly from the optional..? If that's the case, it is a very easy helper method to write yourself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic There may be existing resources which provide authoritative answers and some member of the community might know that.

Comment: @tariksbl Isn't it what `ifPresent` method does? A passed consumer won't execute for empty optional and execute once otherwise.

Comment: (OP here) @AshFrench @JaroslawPawlak I had a case where it would've been convenient to pass an `Optional` to a method accepting a collection.

Comment: This proposal was raised at the mailing list, but i can't see any clear answer. You may find something if you dig long enough. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-April/040652.html

Comment: You mean that something like `op1.map(Collections::singletonList).orElse(Collections.emptyList())` really should be implemented as a language construct? Is this really such a common occurrence?

Comment: @RealSkeptic It's the "FP way" :) probably all the way to Haskell and others. But the argument "it works in another language" is quite flimsy. It may be next to useless in Java.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert on Scala or Haskell, but my belief is that those languages have constructs such as sequence comprehension that make it quite useful for `Option` or `Maybe` to be `Traversable`.

It may be that Java's `Iterable` is analogous to `Traversable` but the rest of the Java language doesn't provide very much support around it. The only thing `Iterable` does in Java is enable its use in an enhanced-for ("for each") loop. Consider for example if Java's `Optional` were to implement `Iterable`. That would allow an `Optional` to be used like this:

```
Optional<T> opt = ... ;
for (T t : opt) {
    doSomethingWith(t);
}
```

It's kind of misleading to write this as a loop, since it executes zero or one times. To be less misleading, one might as well write this:

```
if (opt.isPresent()) {
    doSomethingWith(opt.get());
}
```

or preferably

```
opt.ifPresent(this::doSomething);
```

I don't know for a fact the reason that `Optional` was not made `Iterable`. The Java 8 lambda expert group had several face-to-face meetings where a bunch of things were probably discussed and never written down. I can easily imagine this topic being raised at such a meeting, and dismissed as not being very useful, given the existence of much more useful alternatives such as `ifPresent`.